# Who is the Chessman of "Life of a King"?

Tags: character, life-of-a-king

In the movie *Life of a King*, Eugene Brown starts a youth chess club to teach children to think before they move.  Eugene himself learned his wisdom from a fellow inmate, only referred to as Chess Man in the movie.  Who is the mysterious Chess Man of *Life of a King*, who teaches Eugene Brown about life and chess, and what is his story?

Comment: The character's (nick)name is actually "Searcy".